# mysql - how do I join a sum of two counts?

Tags: mysql, join, count

I currently have a table of match results

```
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| hometeam | awayteam | p1home | p2home... | p1away | p2away... | homescore | awayscore |
+----------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

which I query with the rather clunky

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(hometeam)
FROM fixture_data
WHERE (p1home = '$playerID' OR p2home = '$playerID' OR...)
AND hometeam = '$teamname')
+
(SELECT COUNT(awayteam)
FROM fixture_data
WHERE (p1home = '$playerID' OR p2home = '$playerID' OR...)
AND awayteam= '$teamname')
AS matches_played
```

to get the number of matches a particular player $playerID has played for a particular team $teamname

The table players is a simple

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| playerID | firstname | surname   |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

At the moment after calling

```
SELECT * FROM players
```

I call the initial query via PHP for each player as I'm struggling to join the two queries together into one single MYSQL query to result in a table

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| playerID | firstname | surname   | matches_played |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Is this possible?    Or is my current solution using PHP going to be as efficient as it's going to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
SELECT p.playerID, p.firstname, p.surname, COUNT(*)
  FROM players p, fisture_data f
 WHERE p.playerID='$playerID'
    AND (((p.playerID = f.p1home OR p.playerID=f.p2home...) AND f.hometeam='$teamname')
        OR ((p.playerID = f.p1away OR p.playerID=f.p2away...) AND f.awayteam='$teamname'))
GROUP BY p.playerID, p.firstname, p.surname
```

But the model is not optimal, you should create a new table where you store the link player/match/team.

Comment: Thanks - the table formatting was a hangover of converting the data from a spreadsheet where it was already in that format - I can see how that will be more efficient so will try to implement that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest combining those queries into one like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS matches_played
FROM fixture_data
WHERE (p1home = '$playerID' OR p2home = '$playerID' OR...)
AND ( awayteam= '$teamname' OR hometeam = '$teamname')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make this easier on yourself if you take the player list out of the match table and put it into a separate table of player, team, match. Then your sum would be a matter of joining the three and counting matches. It wouldn't matter if the player was home or away or even how many ppl played a given match.